# NESTED INNER JOIN using MS Access 2003 via ODBC

Tags: sql, odbc, inner-join

If this works:

```
SELECT COUNT(t1.ID) AS count FROM Project t1
INNER JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT t.Site,t.id FROM _Equipment_id t WHERE t.OEM LIKE '%ABC%') t2 ON t1.Site=t2.Site AND t1.id=t2.id
```

and this works:

```
SELECT COUNT(t3.ID) AS count FROM Wall t3
INNER JOIN Project t1 ON t3.Project_number=t1.Project_number
```

Why doesn't this work:

```
SELECT COUNT(t3.ID) AS count FROM Wall t3
INNER JOIN Project t1 ON t3.Project_number=t1.Project_number
INNER JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT t.Site,t.id FROM _Equipment_id t WHERE t.OEM LIKE '%ABC%') t2 ON t1.Site=t2.Site AND t1.id=t2.id
```

Ultimately, I have 10 tables like the Wall table that I  am trying to get a total count from the first SELECT....

Comment: Undefined results on the client side of my ASP page..., which is the same error when there is a syntax error in the SQL statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT COUNT(t3.ID) AS count FROM Wall t3
INNER JOIN (Project t1 
INNER JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT t.Site,t.id FROM _Equipment_id t WHERE t.OEM LIKE '%ABC%') t2 
ON t1.Site=t2.Site AND t1.id=t2.id)
ON t3.Project_number=t1.Project_number
```

Maybe it's just a syntax error? [Office Help](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/inner-join-operation-HP001032241.aspx) at the bottom where they mention nesting. The other possibility is that the aliases are somehow scoped so that they are not available to the join, but I'm no expert on MS Access. Maybe you should just try dropping the aliases altogether.

Comment: This worked!  If I have 10 tables like Wall that have a project_number, what is the simplest SQL statement to get the total count? (in the past I would just loop through an array or table names and total using each count)

Comment: You can try adding `UNION` to the bottom of the query and then repeat the same query as above with the next Wall table. `UNION` should just sum up the results of all queries. If this doesn't work as expected, you may have to do `COUNT(t3.ID) AS TotalCount`, `COUNT(t4.ID) AS TotalCount`,..., `COUNT(tx.ID) AS TotalCount` so the alias stays the same in all queries.

Comment: Thanks, I was hoping to take the 10 wall tables, union all to have one large table, and then just add the two inner joins, but I can't get that syntax to work.  My foreach loop works fine, just seems wasteful...

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of minor issues with your code: a table name that starts with an underscore character (`_Equipment_id`) and an `AS` clause ("alias") that is a SQL keyword (`AS count`). When these are corrected, your SQL is valid SQL-92 syntax.

Sadly, the problem is that Access (ACE, Jet, whatever) does not support the SQL-92 Standard. Access insists that each nested `JOIN` clause is put in parentheses.

[Aside: `JOIN`s in parentheses are allowed in Standard SQL because it can potentially change the query results. However Access, does not respect the order specified by the coder and allows itself to evaluate `JOIN`s in order it sees fir. So not only Access's syntax non-compliant with the Standard, there is also a loss of functionality! However, this further problem with Access will have no ill effect for this particular query.]

You have two `JOIN`s in the same scope here:

```
...
INNER JOIN Project t1 ON t3.Project_number=t1.Project_number
INNER JOIN
...
```

Your code needs to work around Access's problem by enclosing the `JOIN` in parentheses; because all your `JOIN`s are `INNER` flavour, it probably doesn't matter where they go.

Also, as regards correcting your `AS` clause, Access again doesn't support Standard SQL's quoted identifiers (`...AS "count"...`) and insists you use its proprietary square brackets syntax (`...AS [count]...`) -- of course, you could choose a different name but there may exist application code that relies on it.

Code to workaround both Access problems:

```
SELECT COUNT(t3.ID) AS [count] 
  FROM (Wall t3
       INNER JOIN Project AS t1 
          ON t3.Project_number = t1.Project_number)
       INNER JOIN (
                   SELECT DISTINCT t.Site,t.id 
                     FROM _Equipment_id AS t 
                    WHERE t.OEM LIKE '%ABC%'
                  ) AS t2 
          ON t1.Site = t2.Site 
             AND t1.id = t2.id;
```