# Powershell won't run SELECT queries with VIEWS

Tags: sql-server, excel, powershell

I created a VIEW to avoid nesting `SELECT` statement because Powershell script hangs when trying to execute

[Powershell won't run nested SQL Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26655881/powershell-wont-run-nested-sql-query/)

Now the PowerShell script hangs when trying to execute statement with VIEW

```
$SQL10 = "SELECT DISTINCT dbo.Computers.Computer_Name,  
IP_Address, COUNT(Computer_ID) AS Num_Computer_ID  
FROM dbo.Computers, [V_Duplicate_ID]  
WHERE dbo.Computers.Computer_Name =  [dbo].[V_Duplicate_ID].[Computer_Name]
AND dbo.Computers.COMPUTER_NAME LIKE '%s001'  
AND dbo.Computers.IP_Address LIKE '%.100'  
GROUP BY dbo.Computers.Computer_Name, IP_Address  
ORDER BY Num_Computer_ID DESC"

...


$ws = $wb.Worksheets.Item(10)
$ws.name = "GUP Dup ID"

$qt = $ws.QueryTables.Add("ODBC;DSN=$DSN3;UID=$username;PWD=$password", $ws.Range("A1"), $SQL10)

if ($qt.Refresh()){
    $ws.Activate()
    $ws.Select()
    $excel.Rows.Item(1).HorizontalAlignment = $xlCenter
    $excel.Rows.Item(1).VerticalAlignment = $xlTop
    $excel.Rows.Item("1:1").Font.Name = "Calibri" 
    $excel.Rows.Item("1:1").Font.Size = 11 
    $excel.Rows.Item("1:1").Font.Bold = $true 
 }
```

How can I get this to work so SQL query is output to the EXCEL worksheet?

UPDATE

I created view

```
CREATE VIEW V_DUPLICATE_ID AS
SELECT DISTINCT Computer_Name, IP_Address, COUNT(Computer_ID) AS Num_Computer_ID
FROM dbo.Computers
WHERE Computer_Name in (SELECT DISTINCT Computer_Name
                        FROM dbo.Computers
                        WHERE dbo.Computers.COMPUTER_NAME LIKE '%s001'
                        AND dbo.Computers.IP_Address LIKE '%.100'
                        GROUP BY Computer_Name,IP_Address
                        HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT Computer_ID) > 1)
AND dbo.Computers.COMPUTER_NAME LIKE '%s001'
AND dbo.Computers.IP_Address LIKE '%.100'
GROUP BY Computer_Name, IP_Address
```

And updated the script

```
$SQL10 = "SELECT * FROM [V_Duplicate_ID]
ORDER BY Num_Computer_ID DESC"

...

$ws = $wb.Worksheets.Item(10)
$ws.name = "GUP Duplicate ID"

$qt = $ws.QueryTables.Add("ODBC;DSN=$DSN3;UID=$username;PWD=$password", $ws.Range("A1"), $SQL10)

if ($qt.Refresh()){
    $ws.Activate()
    $ws.Select()
    $excel.Rows.Item(1).HorizontalAlignment = $xlCenter
    $excel.Rows.Item(1).VerticalAlignment = $xlTop
    $excel.Rows.Item("1:1").Font.Name = "Calibri" 
    $excel.Rows.Item("1:1").Font.Size = 11 
    $excel.Rows.Item("1:1").Font.Bold = $true 
 }
```

The script is still hanging.

Comment: Not likely the root cause, but consider using [modern joins](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) instead of Ansi-92 syntax.

Comment: Why not just create a view to provide the desired output of this query?  The entire purpose of a view is to eliminate this sort of problem.

Comment: @jbarker2160 I tried creating the view for the entire query but powershell script still hangs

Comment: I solved it. For some reason it now works.